# Upper Bound on number of Elementary Row Operations

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:** Show that an $n \times n$ matrix with real coefficients can be put into *Reduced Row Echelon Form (RREF)* by a sequence of at most $n^2$ elementary row operations.

This feels simple, but proving this somehow eludes me. I thought about proceeding by Induction - for a given $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix, consider the upper left block $n \times n$ matrix - by the Inductive Hypothesis, this can be put into RREF after at most $n^2$ steps. Now, for each non-zero element $a_i$ in the $(n+1)$-st row lying below a leading $1$ (and also not in the rightmost position), we can make it zero by the row operation $R_{n+1} \rightarrow - a_i R_j + R_{n+1}$, where $R_j$ is the row containing the leading $1$.

But at this point, I run into an annoying problem - what if $a_i$ lies below a column of $n$ zeroes, thus preventing it from being transformed into zero by the above described row operation? Intuitively, I would want to perform a row swap, but I don't see how to proceed from here.

Any insights/hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Go column by column. Processing the first column takes $n$ operations. Processing the second column takes $n$ operations. Etc.

Comment: I had this idea too, but does this rule out the case where the leading $1$ of a non-zero row appears to the *left* of a leading $1$ of a row above it? I guess if this happens, that means we did not need to use the full $n$ operations, so we could spare one operation for the row swap? It is difficult to encode this argument rigorously though...

Comment: I don't understand the scenario. In my approach, you're never looking for "the leading 1 of a row". You start by cleaning up the first column, then you clean up the second column, etc. For each column you do at most n operations (including a possible row swap).

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what you mean by "processing the first column"?

Comment: @Hello Assume for example that the entry a_11 (top-left) is zero, but a_21 (second row, first column) is not zero. Then we swap first and second rows (1st row operation). Now multiply the first row by an appropriate value to make a_11 = 1 (2nd row operation). Now add the appropriate multiple of the first row to the third row to make a_31 = 0 (3rd row operation). Etc. At the end of this, the first column is one 1 and n-1 0s, and we have made n row operations.

Comment: Then we do the same thing with the second column. We make sure there is one 1 and n-1 0s in the second column, again using n row operations.

Sometimes there are only 0s left in a column (below the previous 1s). In that case we skip that column.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. Basically, as much as possible, for each column (barring columns of all zeroes, which saves us operations anyway), you make the elements in the main diagonal equal to $1$ by row swaps and multiplying by suitable factors. Ensuring that there is one $1$ and $n-1$ $0$s can then be done in at most $n$ steps by EROs. Am I understanding this correctly?